# Override Django Handler404 with JSON type handler

Tags: python, json, django

I'm using Django 2.0.1 and I'm trying to override Django 404 page with another response. Instead of returning a regular template, I want to return a JSON response.

here is my project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import handler404
from django.http import JsonResponse

 urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('accounts.urls'))
]


def response404(request, status=200, message='Not Found', data=None):
    data = {'status': 404, 'message': message, 'data': data}
    return JsonResponse(data=data, status=status)

def response500(request, status=500, message='Not Found', data=None):
    data = {'status': status, 'message': message, 'data': data}
    return JsonResponse(data=data, status=status)



handler404 = response404
handler500 = response505
```

and in accounts/urls/py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import UserView, AuthenticationView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', UserView.as_view()),
    path('auth/', AuthenticationView.as_view()),
]
```

but by it 404 returns it still return me the basic Django 404 page even if I change Debug option to True in settings.py file

Answer (score 2):

Handler 404 should not call the function and function's first argument is request. Change your code to this:

```
def response(request, status=200, message='Not Found', data=None):
    data = {'status': 404, 'message': message, 'data': data}
    return JsonResponse(data=data, status=status)

handler404 = response
```

Comment: It seems like it still returns the default 404 handler

Comment: @ZulwiyozaPutra custom 404 page works only with DEBUG=False.

Comment: still return Django default handler 'Server Error (500)'

Comment: sure. one second

Comment: 500 server error returned whenever I request a wrong path. I expected it return my custom 404 handler

Comment: @ZulwiyozaPutra your response function should take request as first argument. Also rename it to response404 since you use this name in line handler404=response404

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164517/discussion-between-zulwiyoza-putra-and-neverwalkaloner).

Comment: Was a solution to this ever found? If so could someone post an answer.